# Displaying Excel data in a table in richtextbox vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net, richtextbox, excel-interop

I am using gembox.spreadsheet to import data in rich text box, here's the code :

```
 Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
    Dim ef As ExcelFile = ExcelFile.Load(OpenFileDialog1.FileName)
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    For Each sheet As ExcelWorksheet In ef.Worksheets
        sb.AppendLine()
        sb.AppendFormat("{0} {1} {0}", New String("-"c, 25), sheet.Name)
        For Each row As ExcelRow In sheet.Rows
            sb.AppendLine()

            For Each cell As ExcelCell In row.AllocatedCells
                If cell.ValueType <> CellValueType.Null Then
                    sb.Append(String.Format("{0} [{1}]", cell.Value, cell.ValueType).PadRight(25))
                Else
                    sb.Append(New String(" "c, 25))
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
    bodytxt.Text = sb.ToString()
End Sub
```

The problem is , when the .xls file is imported/loaded in the bodytxt textbox, it looks very weird...Something like :

```
 ------------------------- Sheet1 -------------------------
 [String]                Pic [String]             Unique id [String]       
 Prefix [String]          First name [String]      Last name [String]       
 Gender [String]          Title [String]           Company [String]         
Phone [String]           Mobile [String]          Fax [String]             
B.Email [String]         P.Email [String]         Reference [String]       
Address [String]         Address 2 [String]       Country [String]         
City [String]            Zip [String]             Facebook [String]
```

Is there any way to display the data like excel displays the data/show the data in a table/or at least arrange the data's properly one after one because it looks very messy(i arranged them in the post differently so that they would show in a code block).Any way to do so ?

**UPDATE 1**

I figured something out..And this may help every one who are looking for a way to create a table in rich textbox. Let me explain a few things first.Inserting a table in rich textbox is quiet impossible (as far as I think) or at least creating a cutomizable table in rtxtbox like MS WORD is quiet impossible/difficult.... But what if we can find another way to do so? Let us think for a while.... A DATA GRID VIEW CAN LOAD DATA FROM EXCEL, right? NOW HOW ABOUT LOADING THE DATA IN A DATAGRIDVIEW AND THEN ADDING THE ROWS' CELL VALUES IN THE RICH TEXT BOX ..AND AFTER EVERY ROW , WHY NOT ADD A BUNCH OF  "---"(dashes)? THEN EVERY ROW WOULD LOOK SEPARATE AND WOULD GIVE US A TABLE-ish LOOK....! The code for both C++ and VB.net are given below :

**C++**

```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.ComponentModel;
   using System.Data;
   using System.Drawing;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Threading.Tasks;
   using System.Windows.Forms

 'populate your dgvw first
 'Create a button to add data from dgvw to rtxtbox

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {

            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "-";

            for(int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
            {

                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\t" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() + "\t";

            }

            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n";
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"; 'the dashes vary on the cell width/cell number so add as many dashes as u need
            richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\n";
        }

    }
}
}
```

**VB.NET**

```
 'use the same namespaces as c++(if required)

 'populate dgvw
 'add a button to transfer data from dgvw to richtxtbx

 Public sub Button1_click
                 For i As Integer = 0 To dgvw1.Rows.Count - 2
        RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + "-"
        For j As Integer = 0 To dgvw1.Columns.Count - 1
        Try
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbTab + dgvw1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() + vbTab
        Catch ex as exception
        End try  ' The try statement is used so that OBJECT REFERENCE NOT SET TO AN INSTANCE OF OBJECT error can be prevented as it happens when a cell value is null
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbLf
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbLf
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

This may not be the perfect solution but this will get the job done and you can make any changes you want.... THIS IS WHAT I GOT SO FAR AND I WILL UPDATE AS SOON AS I FIND SOMETHING NEW

Comment: Seems like there is an extra space before [String], Prefix [String], First name [String], etc. Try `cell.Value.ToString().Trim()`

Comment: is it possible to display the data in some sort of table ? or like excel displays data?

Comment: @djv. can you please [Read my this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47366431/table-in-richtextbox/47367207?noredirect=1#comment81686897_47367207) and help me out

Answer (score 0):

It may not be an answer to your question but as far as i think,if any of your cell value is null then youl'ld get a "Object reference not set to an instance of object" error in

```
   RichTextBox1.Text = RichTextBox1.Text + vbTab + dgvw1.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() + vbTab
```

So i suggest you using a **TRY STATEMENT** here...

Comment: Well, i already figured that out..At first i couldn't understand what the problem is but then googled for a while and fixed it myself...But thanks anyway.I would re-edit my post