# Table in richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

In my previous question, I posted a code that adds a table (not actually, just adds data to the richtxtbx from dgvw) in a rich text box ..The code is:

```
  For i As Integer = 0 To dg2.Rows.Count - 2
        SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + "-"
        For j As Integer = 0 To dg2.Columns.Count - 1
            Try
                SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + vbTab + dg2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() + vbTab
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
            SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + vbLf
            SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + "--------------------------------------------" + vbLf
            SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + vbLf
        Next
    Next
```

The results look like this :

```
 --------------------------------------------

 88795446   
 --------------------------------------------

 Mr.    
 --------------------------------------------

 Raiyan 
 --------------------------------------------

 rashid 
 --------------------------------------------

 Male   
 --------------------------------------------
```

I hope you see what the problem is.. Each cell's value is being added in a new line.. How do I generate a view like this:

```
 HEADER TEXT        HEADER TEXT      HEADER TEXT
 ------------------------------------------------
  Mr.               ABC               0123456789
 ------------------------------------------------
  Mr.               DEF               987654321
 ------------------------------------------------
  Mr.               GHI               898989898
```

I mean all cell values of a row would be in one line... The next line would be filled with dashes..... Then the next will contain the cell values of the next rows....

I know my code is correct but maybe I am having some "ARRANGING THE CODE" issue... Or is this happening because of my rich textbox size? The reason why I'm thinking so is because when I add data from a dgvw containing 2/3 columns, it works as expected.. So how to fix it or achieve the look I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this would help

```
 SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + vbLf
            For i As Integer = 0 To dg2.Rows.Count - 1

                For j As Integer = 0 To dg2.Columns.Count - 1
                    Try
                        SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + "• " + dg2.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString() + " •"
                    Catch ex As Exception
                    End Try
                Next
                SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + vbLf
                SendMail.bodytxt.Text = SendMail.bodytxt.Text + "------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + vbLf
            Next
```

This might even give you a better look.You must add as many "-"(dashes)as you need.Let me know if it worked

Comment: OMG! You have saved my day twice now!!! Yes it works....and adding the "•" was a great idea...!!!!

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned that when you add data to the rich text box from a datagridview that has a few columns..and then you get the result as desired..Then why not setting the WordWarp property of the Rich-text-box property to true and then add the data. Then i guess a row's cells' value wouldn't go to the next line and maybe you would be able to generate the look you want.

Comment: actually , i am just a beginner,so pardon my mistake